# Can I use react component property inside PostCss style

Tags: css, reactjs, postcss

I'm investigating 3rd party react with PostCss component

in which I see property `isOpen` received from outside

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './Modal.css';

class Modal extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      isOpen,
    } = this.props;

    const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

    const ModalClassName = cx({
      Modal: true,
      isOpen: isOpen,
    });

    return (
      <div className={ModalClassName} tabIndex={0}>

        ... modal content ...

      </div>
    )
  }
}

Modal.propTypes = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default Modal;
```

in Modal.css I can see style to hide this modal component

```
:local(.Modal) {
  &:not(:local(.isOpen)) {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* -------------   I miss this one as well  ------------- */
:local(.isOpen) {
  @media print {
    position: static !important;
  }
}
```

Is this `isOpen` in CSS same variable passed to component as a property  or `isOpen` name just a coincidence?
If yes, how come `isOpen` is visible within CSS? Could you please give me reference where I read about this.

After useful clarifications from @JAM let me rephrase my question.

How value in Modal property `Modal.props.isOpen` can trigger css style `.isOpen` and affect visibility of Modal component. The question is not about classnames library.

```
:local(.Modal) {
  &:not(:local(.isOpen)) {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How value in Modal property Modal.props.isOpen can trigger css style .isOpen and affect visibility of Modal component.

`isOpen` is (in simple terms) a class name imported from the css module `Modal.css` (from `styles`).

So, in your component you can then compose the classes exposed from `styles` as you choose, for example:

```
<div className={`${styles.Modal} ${styles.isOpen}`} />
```

The reason the `.Modal` is hidden when `.isOpen` is not part of the class name, is due to the CSS rules specified for the selector `.Modal:not(.isOpen)`, or as specified in the css module:

```
:local(.Modal) {
  &:not(:local(.isOpen)) {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

So, when the element has the class `Modal isOpen`, the element is visible. When the element has the class `Modal` but is missing `isOpen`, the element will be visibly hidden.

There is no direct correlation between the class name `isOpen` and te component's prop `isOpen`. The `isOpen` prop value is only used to control if the class should be set or not.

---

> Is this isOpen in CSS same variable passed to component as a property or isOpen name just a coincidence?

I am guessing that `isOpen` from the component is meant to reflect the `:local(.isOpen)` selector in the `Modal.css` [css module](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

Based on the reading [here](https://gist.github.com/heygrady/316bd69633ce816aee1ca24ab63535db), it seems that

this: *(binding styles to classnames)*

```
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import styles from './Modal.css';

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

const ModalClassName = cx({
    isOpen: true,
});
```

is equal to this: *(referencing styles)*

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import styles from './Modal.css';

const ModalClassName = classNames({
    [styles.isOpen]: true,
});
```

Because you are using [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), the result of `ModalClassName` in any of the cases above will resolve into a string, to something like `Modal__isOpen___hash` when `isOpen` is `true` above. When `isOpen` is false, the result will be an empty string.

[`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) is just a simple JavaScript utility for conditionally joining classNames together.

It supports [binding to css module styles](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#alternate-bind-version-for-css-modules) (by using `import classnames from 'classnames/bind'`) as referenced in detail above.

Comment: "[styles.isOpen]: isOpen" this makes sense. I was wondering if PostCss processor can reaply styles at run-time based on changed value of isOpen. This property changed every time user clicks button on owner of this Modal. Can PostCss render new style when property changed?I thoought that once styles processed they are kinda static.

Comment: @AlexeiP To clarify, css module (`Modal.css`) is static, and has nothing to do with render. The `classnames` package is just a utility function to better work with classnames (joining and conditionally joining classes). I've updated the answer to include a reference to more info about css modules.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the original post with a rephrased question at the bottom.

Comment: @AlexeiP I've updated the answer to better try to answer your question.

Comment: "When isOpen is false, the result will be an empty string." That I was starting to suspect. Empty string for class will trigger condition not(:local(.isOpen)) to true and hide Modal. Thank you!